# Parallel sorting a dictionary and returning the first k items

Tags: python, sorting, numba

One approach to returning the first `k` items of a sorted dictionary is shown in the code snippet below:

```py
dict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)[:k])
```

Therefore, is there a more efficient approach (for instance, using parallelism as promoted by [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/)) that increases the efficiency?

To better understand, suppose that the dictionary looks like this:

```py
import random

dictionary = {}
num_docs, num_queries = 128, 128000
for query_idx in range(num_queries):
    docs_scores = {}
    for doc_idx in range(num_docs): 
        docs_scores[f"doc_{doc_idx}"] = random.random()
    dictionary[f"query_{query_idx}"] = docs_scores
# {
#     "query_0":{
#         'doc_0': 0.108, 'doc_1': 0.143, ..., 'doc_127': 0.447
#     },
#     ...
#     "query_127999":{
#         'doc_0': 0.847, 'doc_1': 0.431, ..., 'doc_127': 0.744
#     }
# }
```

And the task requires selecting the k best-scored documents for every query (for a huge set of queries).

Comment: Are the values in the dictionary counts of something? If so, you can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of a plain `dict`, and it has a [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method which doesn't require sorting the whole dictionary. Otherwise, you can use [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest).

Comment: If you only need the `k` first key-value pairs then you don't have to sort the entire dictionnary. You can be more efficient (if `k` << `len(dictionary)`) by finding the `k` lowest pairs (and sorting only these), iteratively. This ensures a linear time algorithm.

Comment: `heapq.nlargest` seems promising, so I am going to evaluate it. However, I am looking forward to an approach that leverages all the available processor cores.

Comment: It's unspecific. See [ask]. Research more and choose a proper algorithm such as merge sort or sample sort, implement a prototype and ask a specific question with a [mre]. Also, what is the order of ```k```?

Comment: Numba cannot operate directly on reflected dictionary (ie. pure-Python ones). It needs typed dictionary. Converting the former to the later is pretty slow defeating the use of Numba in this case.